# How do you use st_interpolate_aw with polygon layers that legitimately include point and line intersections?

Tags: r, gis, r-sf

I am trying to use st_interpolate_aw() to assign values from one polygon layer to another polygon layer (voting district vote totals assigned to census tracts). The operation fails because st_interpolate_aw() calls st_intersection() which finds point and line intersections that then get treated as points, lines, or geometrycollections and break the subsequent code casting geometries to multipolygons (I get the error "Error in st_cast.POINT(x[[1](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/860)], to, ...) : cannot create MULTIPOLYGON from POINT")

Within st_interpolate_aw the relevant code looks like this where 'x' is my first polygon layer and 'to' is my second:

```
i = st_intersection(st_geometry(x), st_geometry(to))
idx = attr(i, "idx")
i = st_cast(i, "MULTIPOLYGON")
```

If I look at summary(i) after running st_intersection I can see multiple POINTS, GEOMETRYCOLLECTIONS and LINESTRINGS that were created in addition to the desired POLYGONS and MULTIPOLYGONS. This is not a problem of messy layers per se--we should expect point and line intersections when comparing these kinds of administrative boundaries, but they shouldn't be relevant for interpolation purposes and could be reasonably dropped. The problem is that st_cast doesn't seem set up to make allowances.

I expect the answer to this question is to figure out what parameters I can set via ... in st_interpolate_aw to alter the behavior of st_intersection() or st_cast() to make this work. Alternatively, there may be a path through tricks like st_set_precision() or st_snap() to pre-process my polygons so this doesn't happen (see somewhat relevant back and forth [here](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/860)). I have already run st_is_valid() on my polygons and they are fine. Also, I fundamentally think that st_intersection is behaving appropriately with regards to the data, and that it is st_cast not being willing to drop geometries with no area that causes the problem.

The example below doesn't get me all the way to the solution, but it is small, draws on polygons from the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/vignettes/sf1.html), and generates the same error as my code when running st_interpolate_aw(). If the example below could be run so that st_cast doesn't return an error I think I could get st_interpolate_aw to work

```
a <- st_polygon(list(cbind(c(0,0,7.5,7.5,0),c(0,-1,-1,0,0))))
b <- st_polygon(list(cbind(c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,0),c(1,0,.5,0,0,0.5,
        -0.5,-0.5,1,1))))
c<-st_sfc(a,b)
plot(c)
i <- st_intersection(c[[1]],c[[2]])
i=st_cast(i,"MULTIPOLYGON")
```

Comment: Does `st_collection_extract(i, 'POLYGON')` help at all?

Comment: It probably would, but that would involve making a custom version of st_interpolate_aw. I have to believe that I am still working with basic functionality for that function in this case and just can't figure out how to invoke it properly.

Comment: Why would it require that? Perhaps you could make a small reproducible example that uses `st_interpolate_aw`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the clear example. A small reprex is

```
library(sf)
a <- st_polygon(list(cbind(c(0,0,7.5,7.5,0),c(0,-1,-1,0,0))))
b <- st_polygon(list(cbind(c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,0),c(1,0,.5,0,0,0.5,
        -0.5,-0.5,1,1))))
c<-st_sfc(a,b)

aa = st_sf(value = 1, geom = c[1])
bb = st_sf(value = 2, geom = c[2])
cc = st_sf(value = 3, geom = c[1] + c(.5,.5))
st_interpolate_aw(aa, cc, extensive = TRUE)

cc = st_sf(value = 3, geom = c[1] + c(1,1))
st_interpolate_aw(aa, cc, extensive = TRUE)

st_interpolate_aw(aa, bb, extensive = TRUE)
```

This should now work when you install sf from github (https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/commit/6659234f0ac95bc0c1ebd64a2f26640137f9dbe8)

Comment: So it wasn't just me not knowing the right parameter to pass. That is encouraging. This solution runs with my full data set. I should note that it does not preserve population as it should. Trying to work out whether that is on my end or in the function somehow, but that is for another question and probably git not here. Thanks!